# How to remove Database Table in Wordpress via Function file?

Tags: plugins, mysql

I recently installed Rankmath, I am using different Page Builder, Where the content not readable by the Plugin. So I disabled SEO Analysis from Setting. Now I wonder if we can remove this Table from Daba via **functions.php**. I think removing this table will improve load time.

[image]

Table Name : "wpbr_rank_math_sc_analytics"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `functions.php`

```
function delete_wpbr_rank_math_sc_analytics() {
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['delete_wpbr_rank_math_sc_analytics'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wpbr_rank_math_sc_analytics" );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'delete_wpbr_rank_math_sc_analytics' );
```

Visit this URL: `https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/?delete_wpbr_rank_math_sc_analytics`

Obviously change "yoursite.com" to your actual domain.

I made it so you have to visit a specific URL so it doesn't run every time.

Comment: Thanks Nate for this, But when I added code it returns with 403 error, i delete code from functions.php still error the same

Comment: Weird. A 403 happens when you're trying to access something that you're not allowed to access. Do you have a security plugin installed?